# Lining up Columns in SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-tablix

I have built a report and am having trouble lining up the columns from two tablix in the report.

I have created a report that looks at the counts of records in each table in the relivant database to make sure they have the correct amount of records in them, its a comparison between two databases and the tables held within them.

Dataset1 = new count of records
Dataset2 = old count of records

How can I get the two records sets too line up when one dataset contains more tables than the other data set:

Example of how it is now:

```
Dataset1                Dataset2
TableName  RowCount     TableName  RowCount
-------------------     -------------------
Table1      124          Table1     120
Table2      1            Table2     0
Table3      2658         Table4     5455
Table4      5455         Table6     50
Table5      54
Table6      54
```

Example of how it should be:

```
Dataset1                Dataset2
Tablix1                 Tablix1
TableName  RowCount     TableName  RowCount
-------------------     -------------------
Table1      124          Table1     120
Table2      1            Table2     0
Table3      2658         
Table4      5455         Table4     5455
Table5      54
Table6      54           Table6     50
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that dataset1 always contains all of the table names you want:

Link the Tablix for Dataset2 to Dataset1
(Tablix Properties - Dataset Name)

Get the table names from Dataset1
(Enter Table names field in relevant textbox in tablix)

Use a lookup to get the rowcounts from dataset2
e.g.

```
=lookup(Fields!TableName.Value,Fields!TableName.Value,Fields!RowCount.Value,"Dataset2")
```

If you want the table name in dataset2 to be blank when no rows are returned, use an iif:

```
=IIF(isnothing(lookup(Fields!TableName.Value,Fields!TableName.Value,Fields!RowCount.Value,"Dataset2")),"",Fields!TableName.Value)
```